# Spring boot weblogic deploy error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is my pom.xml file. I am using spring boot dependency for my project. I am trying to deploy project in the weblogic 12c but getting following exception. I tried making tomcat websocket jar scope as provided but no luck. Please help

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Error in the weblogic server while deploying** -

```
    <Mar 30, 2017 8:39:44 PM EDT> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160223> <The resource-env-ref 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration$ClientContextConfiguration/accessTokenRequest' declared in the standard descriptor or annotation has no JNDI name mapped to it. The resource-env-ref must be mapped to a JNDI name using the resource-env-description element of the weblogic proprietary descriptor or corresponding annotation.> 
    <Mar 30, 2017 8:39:44 PM EDT> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160223> <The resource-env-ref   'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientContextConfiguration/accessTokenRequest' declared in the standard descriptor or annotation has no JNDI name mapped to it. The resource-env-ref must be mapped to a JNDI name using the resource-env-description element of the weblogic proprietary descriptor or corresponding annotation.> 
    <Mar 30, 2017 8:39:44 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "89012058186337" for task "2" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:981)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:942)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:564)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:500)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
    <Mar 30, 2017 8:39:44 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 7 task for the application "_auto_generated_ear_" on [partition-name: DOMAIN].> 
    <Mar 30, 2017 8:39:44 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating start task for application "_auto_generated_ear_".> 
    <Mar 30, 2017 8:39:44 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:981)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:942)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:564)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:500)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am new to this website and learning in posting, Thanks for the help