# Spring boot application deploy error on weblogic

Tags: spring-boot, maven-2

trying  to create a basic spring boot application and deploy on weblogic, getting a deployment exeception as below.

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace


Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1025)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:986)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:607)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:539)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

**found the same problem in the below link but its unanswered**'

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130677/spring-boot-weblogic-deploy-error
```

Please help me I have been trying out for 3 days...but no proper help found on searching google.

below is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

              <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                 <artifactId>tomcat-websocket</artifactId>
               </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <archive>
               <manifest>
                  <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
               </manifest>
            </archive>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

below is the weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:context-root>demo</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

below is the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})

public class DemoApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
          return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
       }
}
```

Comment: not getting what changes I have to make to POM.xml please somebody help me in resolving the error

Comment: Where is weblogic.xml?

Comment: Also you need to add "implements WebApplicationInitializer" to your application

Comment: @Pradeep added weblogic.xml and main class which implements WebApplicationInitializer

Comment: Does the exception remains same?

Answer (score 1):

Try to uncomment in your pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```